# Is there a way to send Json payload from a Django REST Created API as payload too another API?

Tags: json, django, api, django-rest-framework

I created an API with Django REST Framework, I want to use Django REST to submit the Json I have created to submit as Payload to another  API. I am not able to see it on the documentation.

```
class CreateListMulesoftRequestAPI(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = MulesoftStreamRequest.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MulesoftRequestSerializer


    # Where validation for Mulesoft goes : @validate_mulesoft_request_create_request_data
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
###I believe I should be able to submit to the difference url here###
        MulesoftAccessRequest = MulesoftStreamRequest(  
            group =request.data.get("group"),
            users =request.data.get("users"),
            notes=request.data.get("notes"),
            correlation_id =request.data.get("correlation_id"), 
            short_description=request.data.get("short_description"), 
        )
        MulesoftAccessRequest.save()

        return Response(
            data=MulesoftRequestSerializer(MulesoftAccessRequest).data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
```

I would like to know if what I am doing is actually possible.

EDIT:
For more context as of now The way I am creating this is via form in the front end through react sagas- That goes to the backend which Django rest framework as an API Json format. My Goal is to use the API I just created to submit it to A serviceNow API request.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to submit the JSON to another API? What API is it? 3rd party API? Which JSON? Please refer to the objects, functions and variables in your code when describing your issue, your question doesn't contain any mention of things in your code.

Comment: This is how I created the first API But I am not sure how to do the second.The API I am submitting it to its ServiceNow to create a request.

Comment: You should never "submit to your own API inside your views", that doesn't make sense. Your views are just python functions that you can call from anywhere else in your code, so just call the function. If needed, create a more generic function that can be used by multiple views to process the data.

Comment: Sorry for the ignorance, But to make sure I am getting what you are saying. It is not good form to use the views as a place to submit the API to another URL. Instead submit it in another function? This is good to know, But I am still new  to APIs request and post so I don't know how. Is there documentation that you could point me to ?

Comment: It’s not really clear what you mean by “submit to another url”. What does the view at that url do with the data? Whatever it’s doing can be wrapped in a python function, eg taking the data and saving it to the database. Just call that function here.